# How to check if a component appears after scroll to bottom in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, scrollview

I created a screen whose information is taken entirely from the database by APIs.
It has now been made so that all parts are loaded in `'componentWillMount'` Lifecycle, and this has caused the loading speed of my screen to be very time consuming.
I want to design the screen in such a way that when the user scrolls down, it is checked whether the component appears on the screen or not. So if the desired component appears after scrolling down, I can call the functions of that component and get the information of that part from the APIs.
I do not know how to do this.
What is the best way to do this? Is there a library that can do this for me?
I spent about 2 hours searching for this goal but to no avail.
I also found libraries for ReactJS that unfortunately can not be used in React Native.
Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Are you using ScrollView or FlatList?

Comment: i'm using ScrollView but i can use FlatList if you have a solution for that

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm developing an online store. I want to call a function when the user scrolls and reaches the product card. This function is actually to get the information of that card from APIs

Comment: Is the product card at the bottom?

Comment: I have 16 rows of products. each rows has 4 columns. and each column is for one of the product card